# Accessing a value in Struts ActionForm from JSP

Tags: java, struts, struts-action

I am a Struts 1.3.10 newbie and I have an issue where I have an `Action` called `RegistrationAction` as follows:

```
    public final class RegistrationAction extends Action{

        @Override
        public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                                     ActionForm form,
                                     HttpServletRequest request,
                                     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception{

           RegistrationForm formBean = (RegistrationForm) form;
           String userid = formBean.getUserid();
           String pwd = formBean.getPassword();
```

The userid and password are then saved to a `HashMap<String, String>` with attributes `_userid` and `pwd`.

`RegistrationAction` then calls a JSP if the validation of the `userid` and `password` are successful. But what I am finding is that in the JSP, the userid is not being displayed using the following code:

```
    <h1>Hello  <bean:write name="RegistrationForm" property="_userid" />!</h1>
```

The matching `ActionForm RegistrationForm` contains the `_userid` field as below:

```
    public final class RegistrationForm extends ActionForm{

        private String _userid = null;

        public String getUserid(){ return _userid; }
        public void   setUserid(String userid){ _userid = userid; }

        ...
```

I know that an instance of `RegistrationForm` is being populated because I can retrieve the entered `_userid` via:

```
    if(err == RegistrationModel.OK){
            System.out.println("Here " + model.getUserid());
```

I thought that a reference to the `RegistrationForm` in the JSP such as:

`<h1>Hello  <bean:write name="RegistrationForm" property="_userid" />!</h1>`

Would work.

Can anyone suggest where I'm wrong?

Thanks to the respondents. The page works now.

Comment: `_userid` is terribly a hateful name of a property that doesn't confirm the naming conventions of Java. You shouldn't be using it anymore.

Comment: Agreed. `_userid` is simply a name used in the Struts example I was following which never worked properly anyway until this question was posted, and another one yesterday. Now that I have the example working, I will be changing the name to `userName` or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSP tags, and the JSP EL, access bean *properties*, and not bean *fields*. So if you pass `_userId`, it will look for a getter method called `get_userId()`. Since you want to access the getter `getUserId()`, you need to use `userId` inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<h1>Hello  <bean:write name="RegistrationForm" property="userid" />!</h1>
```

it doesn't matter what the internal name / coding of your formbean is. All what matters is how the getters and setters are named. Your getter is named `getUserid()` to the javabean property is `userid`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add your RegistrationForm to request

```
request.setAttribute("RegistrationForm",formBean);
```

2) Remove _ from your _userId variable